# Why does recyclerview adapter often changes from livedata observer even though no changes are there?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 2 fragments with a single activity. `Fragment A` and Fragment B. I did some tasks and then If I move from FragmentA to FragmentB and came back by pressing the back button. In that case, the state is not remaining as before, instead, I'm getting a fresh View like the first time. Why?

Actually, I have a `recyclerview` and custom toolbar. If I scroll some item and then move to `fragment B` and came back, I should be in the same state.

**Please note:** This question might be asked a number of times, but my coding scenario is different.

I'm using dagger hilt, kotlin, corutine, viewmodel, live data, recyclerview asynclist differ, and nav component.

Code:
**FragmentA**

```
 private val viewModel: ProductViewModel by viewModels<ProductViewModel>()
```

- **onviewcreated**

  viewModel.getProducts.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
  stopShimmerLayout()
  response.let { productResponse ->
  productAdapter.differ.submitList(productResponse)
  }
  setActionListener()
  })

**ViewModel class**

```
class ProductViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val repository: ProductRepository,
) : ViewModel() {

    val getProducts = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        emit(repository.getProducts())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LiveData will always give you its current value upon loading the view again. If you dont want that then might I suggest moving to Kotlin `Flow` or `MutableStateFlow`

**Update**

If you updated your adapter data (or repository) which you should have done when when something changes like your button then called `getProducts` again to trigger the livedata observer to update your recyclerview you should get the data upon returning.

Here is an example of how I would do it

Example:

ViewModel

```
class ProductViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val repository: ProductRepository,
) : ViewModel() {

    val productsLiveData: MutableLiveData<Products> = MutableLiveData<Products>()

    fun getProductsAsync() {
        val data = repository.getProducts()
        productsLiveData.postValue(data)
    }

    fun updateDataAsync(){
        //Update your repository data
        //Call get products again to propagate the data change to the productsLiveData and recycler view
        getProductsAsync()
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
    viewModel.productsLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{
        //Update recycler view adapter here
        //Anytime you either call getProductsAsync() or updateDataAsync() from your viewmodel this will get called and you should update the adapter
        productAdapter.differ.submitList(productResponse) { setActionListener() })
    }
    viewModel.getProductsAsync()
}
```

Obviously you will need to update the code to fit what you have but this is the basic flow I would do so that whenever you load the fragment it will always have the latest correct data

Comment: that's fine, but data is never changed from API

Comment: It does not matter if the api changed or not, if you had the live data emit something then it will always emit that value when you start observing it again when the view loads

Comment: See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsKXYOLrTXw&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuC_pEfFlZuTmjlY4T3DTtED&index=13&ab_channel=CodinginFlow

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to show me with that video but the code you have does not match what is in the video

Comment: I want to handle saved state like this, https://github.com/codinginflow/ImageSearchApp/blob/Part-13_Handling-Process-Death/app/src/main/java/com/codinginflow/imagesearchapp/ui/gallery/GalleryViewModel.kt

Comment: What happens when you add in the missing code such as the `@Assisted state: SavedStateHandle` like in the example?

Comment: nothing happens the point is poople are using state in a different diff way. now in my case repository.getProducts() is a suspend function. don't know what to do?

Comment: See this: viewModel.breakingNews.observe  ----- this guy is handling in different way: https://github.com/philipplackner/MVVMNewsApp/blob/Adding-and-deleting-articles-in-our-database/app/src/main/java/com/androiddevs/mvvmnewsapp/ui/fragments/BreakingNewsFragment.kt

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for? https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/restore-recyclerview-scroll-position-a8fbdc9a9334

Comment: No, suppose in my item view there is a button, if I click, that button text change will be from Add to Remove. Suppose I clicked any of item, now button text is remove. then went to fragmentB and came back. Now everything performed action is gone.

Comment: I updated my answer, there is no one method fits all here. there are multiple things that you will need to do to be able to save the state of everything. Maybe a more specific question might get you better results instead of what I believe you are trying to ask of how do I keep the state of the fragment of everything that changed

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you so much dear!